# Alternating color by column value HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a HTML table like this.

```
<table class="TableA">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="a">aa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="a">aa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="a">bb</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td class="a">cc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td class="a">dd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td class="a">ee</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td class="a">ee</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can i alternating color by column `<td class="a">` value html?
This result like this

[image]

I have tried this JS code.

My idea is to find all `("td.a")` and compare string. If true `bgColor = "red"`.

```
$(".TableA").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find("td.a")[0].innerHTML == $(this).find("td.a")[1].innerHTML) {
        $(this).find("td.a")[0].bgColor = "red";
    } else {
    $(this).find("td.a")[0].bgColor = "white";
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't understand the problem. What is the issue ??

Comment: is this a sequence or just 1-7?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph is sequence. Above just my demo for test.

Comment: I think I understand, from your code it looks like you want that each group of values will be in red color. right ?

Comment: @OmriAttiya Yup. Pls help me.

Comment: why is `cc` red? if its two consecutive rows

Comment: I want it interleaved and group by color.

Comment: but 4 and 5 have different texts, so how can you make it red? What is your basic logic that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: you want to put the color red based on a sequence? or based in the content that is in the td?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To highlight consequence rows with same text, you can use the `next()` to compare the next element and add class accordingly.

```js
$(".TableA tr").each(function() {
  let now = $(this).find('td').last();
  let next = $(this).next().find('td').last();
  if (now.text() == next.text()) {
    now.addClass('red');
    next.addClass('red');
  }
});
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="TableA">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="a">aa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="a">aa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="a">bb</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td class="a">cc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td class="a">dd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td class="a">ee</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td class="a">ee</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make two sibling `td` that has same innerHTML to be red background, you can try this code, it's easy to understand:

```js
    const testArray = $(".TableA td.a")
    testArray.map(function(index) {
      // Be careful out of the array
      if (index === testArray.length - 1) return 0;
      if (
        testArray[index].innerHTML ===
        testArray[index + 1].innerHTML
      ) {
        testArray[index].style.background = "red";
        testArray[index + 1].style.background = "red";
      } else {
        testArray[index].style.background = "white";
      }
    });
```